# How to return string or JSX element in TypeScript React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting this weird TypeScript error:

```js
import React from 'react'

type Props = {
  children: string
}

const Container = (props: Props) => {
  const isNew = true // make an api call...

  if (isNew) {
    return <NewContainer {...props} />
  } else {
    return <OldContainer {...props} />
  }
}

const NewContainer = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const isSpecial = useIsSpecial()

  if (!children) {
    return null
  }

  if (!isSpecial) {
    return children
  }

  return <a>{children}</a>
}

const OldContainer = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const isSpecial = useIsSpecial()

  if (!children) {
    return null
  }

  if (!isSpecial) {
    return children
  }

  return <a>{children}</a>
}
```

Those get used like this:

```
<Container>foo</Children>
```

I then get these typescript error:

```
'NewContainer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'string | Element' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
'OldContainer' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'string | Element' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

If I remove the `if (!isSpecial) return children`, and change it to `if (!isSpecial) return <span>{children}</span>`, it works fine. Why won't it allow me to return a string? How do I fix this in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case children is a string so you should wrap it with React.Fragment or <></>
but if children was element like below it won't throw an error

```
<Container><p>foo</p></Container>
```

so just add react fragment

```
import React from "react";

const Container = (props) => {
  const isNew = true; // make an api call...

  if (isNew) {
    return <NewContainer {...props} />;
  } else {
    return <OldContainer {...props} />;
  }
};

const NewContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const isSpecial = true;

  if (!children) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!isSpecial) {
    return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
        // or return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return <a>{children}</a>;
};

const OldContainer = ({ children }) => {
  const isSpecial = useIsSpecial();

  if (!children) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!isSpecial) {
    return <React.Fragment>{children}</React.Fragment>;
    // or return <>{children}</>;
  }

  return <a>{children}</a>;
};
const Main = () => (
  <Container>
    <a>foo</a>
  </Container>
);

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 15):

TypeScript's React types are incorrect and disallow `string` as a return value of a component type.

A React component is allowed to return the following types (a React Node):

- null
- boolean
- number
- string
- React Element
- React Portal
- Array of (React Node or undefined)

You can easily test this running the snippet below and observing the component is correctly rendered.

```js
function HelloWorld() { return "Hello, World!"; }
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HelloWorld), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also notice that running `ReactDOM.render("Hello, World!", ...)` works as well, since the `render` function of React DOM expects a valid React Node, and `string` is such.

But you can also use as reference the [`isNode` function of the `prop-types` package](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/044efd7a108556c7660f6b62092756666e39d74b/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L474-L519) or the [Flow's `React$Node` type definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.136/lib/react.js#L13-L20), to verify what a React Node type accepts, both type definitions have been created by <strike>Facebook</strike> Meta itself.

TypeScript maintainers don't seem to be interested in fixing this issue, along with the incorrect `ReactNode` type that wrongly accepts `undefined`, so you can only resort to workarounds such as wrapping the text into a Fragment, as explained in other comments.

Comment: Can you link to where "TypeScript maintainers don't seem to be interested in fixing this issue"?

Answer (score 0):

To please TypeScript where it complains, indicate its desired type explicitly with

```
return children as JSX.Element;
```

or for plain string

```
return "MyTextToRender" as unknown as JSX.Element;
```

to prevent

> Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Element' may be a mistake because
> neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was
> intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. ts(2352)