# returning a string from a component is not a valid jsx element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to writing typescript with react, and the first error I encountered is when I return a string from a component, I don't think this is invalid because react knows how to deal with it:

```
function MyComponent(){
  const Test = ()=> "Hello" 
  return <Test />
}
```

Typescript complains:

> 'Test' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type 'string'
> is not a valid JSX element.

You might say, wrap it in a React fragment.

Although wrapping it in a React fragment works, it's not always cool, take the following example:

```
import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

interface P extends PropsWithChildren {}

function MyComponent() {
  const Button = (props: P) => {
    const { children } = props
    return children
  }
  return <Button>Hello world</Button>
}
```

Typescript complains:

> 'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type
> 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'

Now in order to get around this I will have to write:

```
return (
  <Button>
    <React.Fragment>
      Hello world
    </React.Fragment>
  </Button>
)
```

Is there a way to make this error not get into my way?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is not recognizing your `Test` as a component because the typing is not explicitly defined. To distinguish a regular function from a React component, You can either assign a component type such as `React.FC` or assign a return type of `React.ReactNode` to it.

Comment: Can you write the code? Because `React.FC` doesn't allow to return a string, and ReactNode is just the return type and not the _function_ type, And using ReactNode as the return type on the Button component shows the same error, see the error bellow

Comment: 'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to return and represent a component using React with TypeScript, you need to return a JSX component (as you have already verified,  wrapping it with a fragment).

You can see more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65708282/18656328).

Comment: But this is so annoying